# How can we get an OIDC token during Sign-in with Facebook flow on Web

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, facebook-login

I am manually building the login flow for `Sign-in with Facebook` on the web.
Reference - [Manually Build a Login Flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow).
In this flow, you can exchange the `authorizationCode` with `AccessTokens`. Reference - [Exchange Code for an Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#exchangecode).

But there is no way to retrieve an OIDC token in this flow as per the documentation.

Facebook recently started offering a [Limited Login Mode](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/limited-login). A successful login in Limited Login populates a global AuthenticationToken instance that contains an OIDC token.
Limited Login mode is based on the [OpenID Connect standard](https://openid.net/), and allows users to create new accounts or access existing accounts on your app.
But Facebook Limited Login seems to be related to iOS only at the moment.

Is there any way we can retrieve the OIDC token in the `Sign-in with Facebook` flow on the web as well in order to follow the OpenID Connect Standard?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?